# Stub set later on perform_later ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to stub out an ActiveJob method in Rspec but I cannot really fiddle it out. I'm having an email send class for Mailchimp which is `MailingListUnsubscribeJob`. The call is:

```
MailingListUnsubscribeJob.set(wait: 20.days).perform_later(subject: user, list: "activation")
```

Usually what I do in Rspec when not having the `set(wait: 20.days)` but I have just the `perform_later` I do the following in my specs:

```
allow(MailingListUnsubscribeJob).to receive(:perform_later)
```

but it does not work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using RSpec already, you can use [rpec-activejob](https://github.com/gocardless/rspec-activejob).

It has [matchers you need](https://github.com/gocardless/rspec-activejob#rspec-activejob-matchers):

> If your job uses `set(wait_until: time)`, you can use `.to_run_at(time)`
>   chain after `enqueue_a` call as well.